# XSLT file - Problem with for-each function

Tags: xml, xslt

I've a file similar to the below one:

```
  <catalog>
    <cd0>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year></cd0>
    <cd1>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd1>
    <cd2>
        <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
        <artist>Bob Dylan</artist>
        <country>USA</country>
        <company>Columbia</company>
        <price>10.90</price>
        <year>1985</year>
    </cd2>
    .
    .
    .
</catalog>
```

I would want to extract any element of node `<cd1>`, `<cd2>`, `<cd3>`, etc... with a for-each function but i can't find how to do it....

Could you please help me ?

Comment: It would be a good idea to show us the output you want to achieve, and the code that you have written that doesn't work, then we can see where you are stuck and whether there's some particular part of the language specification that you need advice on.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly guessing what you are trying to achieve, here some comments:

Looping elements in XSLT is most likely a typical beginners approach for processing XML tags. In XML you have to change your thinking. This means not looping tags, but applying templates which fit a certain path (xpath).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="catalog">
    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
      </head>
      <body>
        <ul>
          <xsl:apply-templates />
        </ul>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="catalog/*">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I added a simple sample and here some explanation:

1. Your root tag is called `catalog`, so the xslt processor goes, "Cool here we go" and starts applying the template which fits --> `catalog`.
2. Then in writes out those sample html tags until it encounters the `apply-templates`.
3. It looks for a template `cd0`, `cd1`, and eventually finds a template which fits all child-nodes (*) of catalog. (And adds it's titles for the sake of completeness.)
4. Hope this gets you going. Not sure whether you are generating that xml-layout, but the number should not be part of the tag name. Better:

   `<cd id="0">
    ...
    </cd>`

Why is it better? You can search more easily. Here checking index:

```
  <xsl:template match="cd[@id='1']">
    <li>
      <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

here checking the year:

```
  <xsl:template match="cd[year/.&gt;1985]">
    <li>
   <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>
```

Learing xsl, you will stumble across it 'generating too much output'. This is because default templates are applied which copy traversed xml tags and dump them in your generated output. I usually add this empty default template, it writes --nothing, so you have full control.

```
<xsl:template match="*">

</xsl:template>
```

Some more hints for you and anybody who comes across:
node() is the same as `*`, and the confusing

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

just means:

Use this template for each attribute (@)node OR (|) every tag-node (* or node()) and copy this very node to the output document, recursively applying and thus iterating the source document. Comment tags are ignored.

Hope this gives every newbie a ramp up! Its actually pretty cool and **very efficient** once you know how to use it.

Comment: FYI, `xsl:for-each` is not a loop - and using it here would not only shorten the code but also reduce the amount of processing.